# Array.sort function affecting arrays that I don't think it should affect

Tags: c#, arrays

(Simplified) code:

```
Line 1     Temporary = ArrayX;            
Line 2     Array.Sort(Temporary, ArrayY);
```

I've recorded the following results by stepping through code:

Before Line 1:

```
Array X = 3, 2, 1
Array Y = 1, 2, 3
Temporary = 0 ,0 ,0
```

Before Line 2:

```
Array X = 3, 2, 1
Array Y = 1, 2, 3
Temporary = 3, 2, 1
```

(so far so good)

After Line 3:

```
Array X = 1, 2, 3    //<-- Why is this affected by Line 2??
Array Y = 3, 2, 1
Temporary = 1, 2, 3
```

As you can see, for whatever reason `ArrayX` is affected by the sort function. I honestly can't see any reason why it should be.

EDIT - so should this sort it? It seems a bit clumsy.

```
for (int i =0; i<3; i++)
{
   Temporary[i] = ArrayX[i];
}
```

Comment: `Temporary = ArrayX;` doesn't copy the contents of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're dealing with reference types. `Temporary` and `ArrayX` point to/are references to the same location in memory. Anywhere you use one of those references to modify some value in the collection you're changing the same data. If you want to modify a different version of the same data then you should do something like;

```
        var temp = ArrayX.ToList();
```

Which would return a `List<T>` where `T` is the type of the array (`T[]`). If you then do something like sort `temp` it will sort the copy and `ArrayX` will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing `Temporary = ArrayX` and you are giving them the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

Both Temporary and ArrayX are pointing to same location in memory. They are just two names of same thing. Hence, if you change one, other one is going to change.

Comment: Okay. So is the above a sensible solution? It seems clumsy.

Comment: What you need is a deep copy. It depends on the size of arrays you are dealing with. What I generally have is a little method that uses MemoryStream and a BinaryFormatter that serializes and deserializes object. Although, all of this depends on what the object is and how is it used in application. 
If your array is a value type, CopyTo will work as well.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for help. Answer to evan only because I believe he got there first.

Answer (score 1):

Array is reference types that is why they are referencing the same memory location. If you change one, the second will also  be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are reference types. Assigning an array variable to another does not create a copy of the array but only a copy of the array reference. You can copy arrays like this

```
int[] a = { 2, 5, 2 };
int[] b = new int[a.Length];
Array.Copy(a, b, a.Length);
```

Now `a` and `b` are two distinct arrays. What you do to one of them does not affect the other. But be aware of the fact that if you have an array of some reference type the two arrays will contain copies of references. So modifying a property of an item of the array will modify it in both arrays.

```
class Person 
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
Person[] a = {
    new Person{ Name = "John"}, new Person{ Name = "Sue"}, new Person{ Name = "Pete"}
};
Person[] b = new Person[a.Length];
Array.Copy(a, b, a.Length);
```

Now, sorting array `b`, would not modify array `a`. But modifying a person in one array will modify it in the other as well:

```
a[1].Name = "Jill";
Console.WriteLine(b[1].Name); // ==> "Jill"
```